# Converting PHP script to PDO

Tags: php, mysql

Ive been told my script is vulnerable to attacks and to change it to PDO.I have had a go at this and it is working but displays like this on test.php page.

```
Array 
( 
    [name] => matthew 
    [email] => ''@aol.com 
    [order] => shipped 
    [status] => AU1776 
    [attendeesFR] => 1 
)
```

How do i present this data one after the other without array and all the characters?

PDO Script:

```
    <?php

    $host=""; // Host name
        $username=""; // Mysql username
        $password=""; // Mysql password
        $db_name=""; // Database name
        $tbl_name="members"; // Table name


        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.
                          ';dbname='.$db_name.
                          ';charset=UTF-8',
                    $username, $password);
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username`=:username LIMIT 1');
        $result = $st

        print_r($result);
    ?>
```

Comment: Guess you didn't mean to leave the two `mysql_` lines in the second version…

Comment: What problem are you still having?

Comment: Are there PHP errors? MySQL errors? What does the `print_r` display?

Comment: @Pekka웃 when submit is clicked it goes onto test.php but does not show any results

Comment: print_r displays results from $result = $stmt->fetchObject('DOB', 'email'); therefore DOB and email fields from mysql

Comment: You have missing commas in array (i added line breaks in your post, but didnt changed these commas).

Answer (score 2):

The PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension defines a lightweight, consistent interface for accessing databases in PHP. Each database driver that implements the PDO interface can expose database-specific features as regular extension functions. In other words, you can stop use Mysql functions. Instead, you can use PDO to run MYSQL driver or any other database driver that installed in your server.

You can found some information here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Try this out:

```
<?php

$host=""; // Host name
    $username=""; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name=""; // Database name
    $tbl_name="members"; // Table name

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.
                      ';dbname='.$db_name.
                      ';charset=UTF-8',
                $username, $password);
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username`=:username LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $_POST['textfield'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: this did work however it displays results like this:
Array ( [name] => matthew [email] => ''@aol.com [order] => shipped [status] => AU1776 [attendeesFR] => 1 ). how do i display this one after the other without array and all the characters?

Comment: `$result` is a normal associative array--do what you would do for any other array. E.g., `foreach ($results as $k => $v){ echo "$k => $v\n";}`. This is not a PDO question.

Comment: @FrancisAvila whats k and v

Comment: Key and value. (If you don't know the syntax of a foreach loop, you better consult a basic PHP tutorial!)