# how to present PDO::FETCH_ASSOC data in a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been told my script is vulnerable to attacks and to change it to PDO. I have had a go at this and it is working but displays like this at the top of **test.php** page.

```
Array ( [name] => matthew [email] => ''@aol.com [order] => shipped [status] => AU1776 )
```

How do I present this data one after the other without array and all the characters?

pdo script:

```
<?php

$host=""; // Host name
    $username=""; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name=""; // Database name
    $tbl_name="members"; // Table name

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.
                      ';dbname='.$db_name.
                      ';charset=UTF-8',
                $username, $password);
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username`=:username LIMIT 1');


    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Seeing as this is a Q&A site for programmers and code .. showing some code would be a good start ;)

Comment: Well, `print_r` is useful for debugging, but not for formatting some output. Is your question on creating an HTML table from a PHP array? If, yes it is a duplicate to so many other here on SO.

Comment: @feeela I want to display it in a text field. can i change value="" of tyext field to display the database results

Comment: You've asked the same 30 minutes earlier: [Converting PHP script to PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301006/converting-php-script-to-pdo). There're plenty of examples in the manual, I can't understand why you're trying to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
print_r($result);
```

Use this:

```
echo "The is: ".$result['name'].", and mail is: ".$result['email']." . Status: ".$result['status'];
```

------------EDIT--------------------

To display those results on an input type text:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="<?php echo $result['name']; ?>" />
```

-----------EDIT2---------------------

Very basic example:

```
<?php
 $email = "someone@exa mple.com";//change this line to $email = $_POST['textfield'];

 if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
   echo "E-mail is not valid"; //comment this echo and put a header(fail.html)
  }
 else
{
 echo "E-mail is valid"; //comment this echo and do al pdo stuff
}
?>
```

Comment: can i change value="" of text field to display the database results.

Comment: awesome thanks. one more thing. if some entered wrong email address how can i redirect them to fail.html?

Comment: Thats a total different thing...but when the user input the email, you can check if the email is valid with javascript or jquery on the client side

Comment: after     $stmt->bindValue(':email', $_POST['textfield'], PDO::PARAM_STR); can i not use else(header:fail.html); or something?

Comment: yes you can....example on your first line you check for valid email with php(server side) , if valid do al pdo stuff, else, redirect with header(fail.html)

Comment: its going to test.php but its blank now :(

Comment: lol ok got it working. too many braces. anyway the validation does not work. when i enter a wrong it just leaves the text fields blank